# How to select recursively from query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How one can reuse query results in the most efficient manner?

I have two tables: items and relations. Item can be lonely item or it can be a child of another item. The relationships are maintained in relations table. Item is uniquely identified by depNo, itemNo columns. Here is the sample dataset:

```
create table items
(
itemId int identity (1,1) not null ,
depNo int not null,
itemNo int not null,
name varchar(50),
class int not null, -- 0 - unknown class, 1 - child item
constraint pk_depNo_itemNo primary key (depNo, itemNo)
);

create table relations
(
relId int identity (1,1) not null,
pDepNo int not null,
pItemNo int not null,
cDepNo int not null,
cItemNo int not null,
constraint pk_parent_child primary key (pDepNo, pItemNo, cDepNo, cItemNo)
);

insert into items values (1, 1, 'M1CItem1', 1);
insert into items values (1, 2, 'M1CItem2', 1);
insert into items values (1, 3, 'M1CItem3', 1);
insert into items values (2, 1, 'Master1', 0);
insert into items values (2, 2, 'LItem1', 0);
insert into items values (2, 3, 'LItem2', 0);
insert into items values (2, 4, 'LItem3', 0);
insert into items values (2, 5, 'Master2', 0);
insert into items values (2, 6, 'M2CItem1', 1);
insert into items values (2, 7, 'M2CItem1', 1);

insert into relations values (2, 1, 1, 1);
insert into relations values (2, 1, 1, 2);
insert into relations values (2, 1, 1, 3);
insert into relations values (2, 5, 2, 6);
insert into relations values (2, 5, 2, 7);
```

The following query selects all items satisfying query criteria or its parents if item is a child:

```
with qRes as (
select depNo, itemNo, name, class, pDepNo, pItemNo from items
left outer join relations
on depNo = cDepNo
and itemNo = cItemNo
where name like '%Item1'
)
-- select all results where item is not a child
select depNo, itemNo, name, class from qRes where class <> 1
union
-- select all parents of the children
select B.depNo, B.itemNo, B.name, B.class from qRes A
inner join items B
on A.pDepNo = B.depNo
and A.pItemNo = B.itemNo;
```

Executed query would return:

```
depNo   itemNo  name    class
2           1   Master1 0
2           2   LItem1  0
2           5   Master2 0
```

Are there any better ways to approach such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one level of recursion then your approach is fine, if you will have many levels in the hierarchy then you may want to consider using a recursive approach.

e.g. if I change one of your relationships:

```
UPDATE  Relations
SET     pItemNo = 6
WHERE   cItemNo = 7
```

It then makes this row `{DepNo: 2, ItemNo: 7, name: M2CItem1}` a child of `{DepNo: 2, ItemNo: 6, name: M2CItem1}`, which in turn is a child of `{DepNo: 2, ItemNo: 5, name: Master2}`

The following will return both `M2CItem1` and `Master2`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  depNo, itemNo, name, class, pDepNo, pItemNo, 1 [RecursionLevel]
    FROM    items
            LEFT JOIN relations
                ON DepNo = cDepNo
                AND ItemNo = cItemNo
    WHERE   name like '%Item1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  i.depNo, i.itemNo, i.name, i.class, r.pDepNo, r.pItemNo, RecursionLevel + 1
    FROM    CTE i
            INNER JOIN relations r
                ON i.pDepNo = r.cDepNo
                AND i.pItemNo = r.cItemNo
)
SELECT  DISTINCT c.DepNo, c.ItemNo, i.Name, i.Class
FROM    CTE c
        INNER JOIN Items i
            ON COALESCE(c.pDepNo, c.DepNo) = i.DepNo
            AND COALESCE(c.pItemNo, c.ItemNo) = i.ItemNo
```

However if you only want to return the top most parent you can use:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  depNo, itemNo, name, class, pDepNo, pItemNo, 1 [RecursionLevel]
    FROM    items
            LEFT JOIN relations
                ON DepNo = cDepNo
                AND ItemNo = cItemNo
    WHERE   name like '%Item1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  i.depNo, i.itemNo, i.name, i.class, r.pDepNo, r.pItemNo, RecursionLevel + 1
    FROM    CTE i
            INNER JOIN relations r
                ON i.pDepNo = r.cDepNo
                AND i.pItemNo = r.cItemNo
), CTE2 AS
(   SELECT  c.DepNo, c.ItemNo, i.Name, i.Class, RecursionLevel, MAX(RecursionLevel) OVER(PARTITION BY c.DepNo, c.ItemNo) [MaxRecursionLevel]
    FROM    CTE c
            INNER JOIN Items i
                ON COALESCE(c.pDepNo, c.DepNo) = i.DepNo
                AND COALESCE(c.pItemNo, c.ItemNo) = i.ItemNo
)
SELECT  DepNo, ItemNo, Name, Class
FROM    CTE2
WHERE   Recursionlevel = maxRecursionLevel
```

This would only return `{DepNo: 2, ItemNo: 5, name: Master2}` for the row `{DepNo: 2, ItemNo: 7, name: M2CItem1}` as this is the parent of its parent.

[Working Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df60f/2)

As an aside, I think you should reconsider your schema? What is your identity column for if you are making ItemNo and DepNo a compound primary key? You should probably choose one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the child-parent recursion in the common table expression itself, with a UNION ALL statement, but your approach is pretty much there.

You may want to look at the `Hierarchy` datatype if you have the option of changing the tables.